# Speech Recognizer in haddler seems to open the activity again every time

Tags: java, android, handler, speech-recognition

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    returnedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
            "en");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
            this.getPackageName());
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);


        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
            } else {
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                speech.stopListening();
            }
        }
    });
    ttsManager = new TTSManager();
    ttsManager.init(this);

    Pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    Stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    Resume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume);
    Pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Resume.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Stop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    // -------------------------------------


    //----------------------------------------


    handler = new android.os.Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                    sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // if end-of-line,
                        String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                        Log.e("TAG", sbprint);

                        if(sbprint.contains("ello")){
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                            speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
                            toggleButton.setChecked(true);

                        }




                    }
                    //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                    break;
            }
        };
    };


    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
    checkBTState();

    //--------------------------------------


}
```

I am trying to activate speech like I am pressing the toogleButton, and i copyed the code from the toogleButton to the handler.
 Everything is ok, i mean if i click the toogleButton it works, but when i recive the message that cointains "ello" in the handler, the speechRecognizer starts but closes very quickly, this happens every time i send that message.

Also it seems like a new activity i created when i trigger the handler with that message, but the same functions in the toogleButton work.

Any ideea how can i make this work ? I want functionality in the toogleButton, but in the handler too, so i can trigger speechRecognition with a message or something inside handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're changing the `toggleButton`'s state inside the `Handler`

```
toggleButton.setChecked(true);
```

And this will trigger the `OnCheckedChangeListener`. But this should start the speech recognition again (because you set it to `true`), not stop it.

Try to call only `toggleButton.setChecked(true);` in your `Handler`, see if that resolves the problem, for example:

```
if(sbprint.contains("ello")){
     toggleButton.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: I will check this is 5 minutes :D

Comment: Yes it works, but still opens a new activity or something, becouse if I press back something closes..

Comment: In the handler, it starts a new activity, and with tooglebutton is ok

Comment: In your `Handler` you can call only `toggleButton.setChecked(true);` this should trigger the `OnCheckedChangeListener` and start the speech recognition.

Comment: @LaurentiuSimionescu Cu placere si succes in continuare.

Comment: multam :)  la ce firma esti ?

Comment: @LaurentiuSimionescu Nici una, lucrez ca freelancer.

Comment: hmm.. e bun asa, scoti ceva calumea ? firma se bazeaza pe freelancer si are proiecte da singur nu gasesc..

Comment: @LaurentiuSimionescu Nu castig cat as putea sau as vrea eu sa castig dar nici nu muncesc prea mult. Ca freelancer e greu la inceput, odata ce primest cateva review-uri bune, gasesti proiecte destul de repede.